# Why didn't Thor grieve for his mother, Frigga

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

After Kurse kills Frigga, Odin rushes to his fallen wife and begins to mourn as he holds her corpse tightly in his arms, whilst Thor just stands there behind him with a disinterested demeanour, as if she were just another random Asgardian warrior that had fallen to the enemy. By watching the scene you'd think that she was not his mother at all.

Even Loki, Thor's evil and murderous brother whom killed dozens of people and attempted to conquer Earth in Marvel's 'The Avengers' reacted in they way you'd expect a son to act upon hearing of his mother's death. Why was Frigga so insignificant in Thor's eyes?

Comment: Are you forgetting the literal seconds before Odin runs in where Thor attacks Malekith in rage after seeing Frigga dead?

Comment: Beyond that, should we assume falling down crying inconsolably is the only acceptable response to someone significant to you dying?

Comment: On the contrary, Thor did that very thing when loki was dying

Comment: Grieving is a very personal matter that is different for each person (or in this case "god") and different for every circumstance.  Shocked silence is a very common innitial reaction, and it's never shown any further how Thor deals with the loss of his (step)mother.  Whatever answer is given to this will be opinion based.

Comment: This sort of question is precisely why people who don't burst into tears at every opportune moment are given such grief [sic] in the world. Not everybody mourns like you do. Your question is actually borderline offensive, with your assumptions that Thor's dead mother must be "insignificant" to him (and, by extension presumably, to people who act the same way around you in _your_ life). Try to have a bit of understanding and open your mind. And try asking this question to Thor's face!

Answer (score 13):

**The Norse Warrior Gods don't weep for fallen comrades in the heat of battle. Like the mortals who emulated them, the Vikings, death in battle was not something to weep over, it was to be celebrated as the best death a warrior could have. Odin can be forgiven since this was his wife of over a thousand years.**

- Thor's demeanor was one of battle-lust and revenge-seeking. A revenge so motivated he would work with his step-brother, a god he loathed, to get that revenge. As for his demeanor, he is a warrior-god. They do not shed tears, in public, for fallen comrades no matter how close.
- I do not expect we would ever see Thor shed tears at this point in his character arc. He is still relatively too young, too battle-hardened and rarely emotionally invested in anyone or anything.
- Given that the Asgardians are under attack at the moment, his composure would be what I would expect for the warrior who lead Asgardians into battle hundreds of times and watched dozens of comrades fall over the centuries.
- Though the question is still up for debate in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, in the comic continuity of Earth-616, Frigga is not Thor's mother, Frigga is his step-mother. The Earth-Mother Gaea is his true mother. Odin had a child with Gaea to have a son whose powers would exceed the average Asgardian's.

Answer (score 2):

At this point Thor is dealing with several situations at once... His girl is dying/at risk, his mother has died and his all powerful father is a weeping mess. As a Warrior and "King Elect" of Asgard he HAS to keep it together and it is here he begins to form his plan.